# curl -u equivalent in .Net WebClient class

Tags: .net, curl, foursquare

The question explains it all but here is some more info. I am trying to use 4sq api with C# and need to send username password pair in every request. The API documentations says that "curl -u user:pass" does the job but how can I do it with WebClient? Don't have time to inspect the traffic, maybe someone knows about it...

WebClient.Credential doesn't work by the way.

Thanks.

Comment: Should have searched before asking: webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(authbytes));

Comment: If you found the solution, what about adding the answer yourself so others can benefit from it? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the solution:

webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(authbytes));

authBytes is the password converted to byte array.

Comment: 'Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username/password)' got my plain-text into authbytes

Answer (score 1):

Try using a [CredentialCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential.aspx)