# Best "curl -u" equivalence in C#

Tags: c#, .net, authorization

When we have this curl command:

```
curl -XPUT "https//auth.something.com"
-u "clientId:clientSecret"
```

What should I do to convert it into C#?

`NetworkCredential myCred = new NetworkCredential(clientKey, clientSecret);`

or this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34649812/5531761

or 
`webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + based64;`
([Why should you base64 encode the Authorization header?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33385497/5531761))

Or CredentialCache (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3996838/5531761)

---

My curl conversion

```
using(var webClient = new WebClient()){
    webClient.UploadString("https//auth.something.com","PUT","{ \"data\":\"dummy data\" }");
}
```

Comment: Or put it in the payload like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/31387943/5531761

Comment: Was any of the answers helpful to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("base address");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes("clientId" + ":" + "clientSecret")));
```

Update: based on the updated question

I haven't tried this yet, but could you test this?

```
using(var webClient = new WebClient())
{
    webClient.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes("clientId" + ":" + "clientSecret")));
    webClient.UploadString("https//auth.something.com","PUT","{ \"data\":\"dummy data\" }");    
}
```

Comment: Is `NetworkCredential ` better? I am not supposed to use Http header

Comment: Could you please add a bit of code that you're going to use to make an API call? (it's fine even if it is not working as is)

Comment: @DylanCzenski I have updated the answer, but I haven't really verified this. Could you try?

Comment: I am currently using this one but I prefer not to put it in the header

Answer (score 0):

If can't or won't use `HttpClient` you can use `HttpWebRequest`:

```
string postData= "firstone=" + inputData;
ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding ();
byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes (postData);

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create ("http://target.com");
request.PreAuthenticate = true;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("username", "password");;
request.Method = "PUT";
request.ContentType =  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;    
using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream ()) {
    stream.Write (data, 0, data.Length);
}    
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse ();
response.Close ();
```

MSDN [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-send-data-using-the-webrequest-class).

Alternative authentification options are:

- `request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String*Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(authInfo));`
  HTTP Basic authentication requies everything after "Basic " to be Base64-encoded
- `httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization: OAuth "+acces_token);`

Comment: kinda off topic but what if you have 2 params like "grant_type=client_credtials" and then "name=abc"

Comment: Sure, you can have multiple URL params, e.g. `string.Format("id={0}&name={1}&inputPassword={2}", 123, email, password);`